# What's the easiest way to get rid of unknown margin/padding without using overflow?

Tags: html, css

I've got [this site](http://checkspot.nl/appendo/website/) and when you smaller the viewport to mobile proportions and scroll to the side, you see some white whitespace, over the whole length of the page. Strangely, I can't find where it's coming from.

The only thing I can verify that it's not coming from my own written Javascript and it's probably CSS related. However, after quite some time searching, I'm giving up.

Who can find the bad ass that is causing the white space to the right side of the page?

*// This only happens on mobile devices or when you smaller your viewport*

Thanks! =)

*The title might be a bit off for this problem, but a title as 'How do I get rid of this unknown margin?' would be a bit strange and vague.. So therefor this title.*

Comment: It is definitely something in your CSS. If you resize it and scroll down you will see your horizontal scrollbar will disappear. So your menu is doing something.

Comment: Removing the whole menu does not solve it.. ;)

Comment: It is in your menu, 100% sure of that. Are you familiar with firebug?

Comment: I've removed the whole menu object from the HTML and uploaded it. Reload the page and see the menu is gone, while the whitespace is not. Atleast, not here. - Yes I'm familiar with Firebug, although I prefer Chrome's inspect element.

Comment: It's nearly the same thing. But if you go with your inspector to your menu, you'll see it is larger than your page is.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but if I remove the menu and the whitespace is still there, it's not the menu; Atleast - Not only the menu that's causing it. :) Do note: The menu is fixed with 100% width, while others are positioned relative. - But thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, try this:

remove in your `header .devices {}`, `left:20%;`

Comment: Was typing this, when I saw yours. ;)

Comment: I just noticed that myself, indeed. Just before you wrote it. Thank you! =)

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help! Je hebt trouwens een mooi design ;)

Comment: Dankje! Ik ben er zelf niet helemaal meer weg van, maar dat komt omdat ik er nu al weken naar kijk :p

Comment: Haha, fair enough. Je eigen portfolio is een stuk mooier ;). Je hebt deze ook zelf gemaakt? En welke opleiding heeft je daar gebracht?

Comment: Met deze site ben ik langer bezig geweest dan m'n portfolio - maar dat is vanuit tekst-> usability oogpunt. Maar zowel deze als m'n portfolio komen 100% uit eigen hand (op Parallax plugin na). Skills en inspiratie heb ik allemaal zelf opgedaan; maar atm volg ik een studie 'Communications & Multimedia design' op de hogeschool Rotterdam. :) - Wil je meer weten, add me on Facebook /sanderschaeffer ;)

Comment: ahhh CMD dus :), dat word mijn vervolg op het HBO in Den Haag! Doe nu Applicatie ontwikkeling op Da Vinci In dordrecht. Ben wel benieuwd wat jij van die opleiding vind enzo...? Jammer dat er hier op stack geen privechat zit ofso

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52770/discussion-between-sander-schaeffer-and-drogon)